# Non ECMAScript 6 module to import in a ECMAScript 6 module

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, relay

I have a javascript module in a legacy app.

```
var auth = function ($) {
  this.getAccessToken = function () {
    $.get("Secured/Token")
    .done(function (data) {
        return data;
    })
    .fail(function (e) {
        // assumes the user's session has expired
        if (e.status = 401) location.reload();
    })
  }
};
```

Then, in my new app using relay/react.

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import auth from './auth.js'

export function injectGraphQLServer() {
  var token = auth.getAccessToken();
  Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
    new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:3000/graphql', {
      credentials: 'omit',
      headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer '
      },
    })
  );
 };
```

but auth variable is undefined. 
How should i do this? is this allowed?

Comment: You may forget to export auth function.

Comment: @MRCODER, to elaborate @Anson's comment, have you exported `auth` in `auth.js` like so `export default auth;`?

Comment: @elektronik I did not, because my legacy app already uses that module. And i dont want to modify it. We just incorporated es6 in some parts of the code.

Comment: @MRCODER, if you're using webpack you can use [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader#usage) `const auth = require('exports?auth!./auth.js');`. If you're not using webpack or want to stay spec compliant, you can do it via a global variable or some property in a global namespace.

Comment: SystemJS and Webpack both have solutions for that for "exporting" globals.

Comment: @elektronik Let me try that and get back to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

So, using [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader#usage), this should now work.

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';
var auth = require('exports?auth!./auth.js');

export function injectGraphQLServer() {
  var token = auth.getAccessToken();
  Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
    new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:3000/graphql', {
      credentials: 'omit',
      headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth().getAccessToken();
      },
    })
  );
 };
```